# How to use OpenJDK 8 in Spring MVC application instead of Oracle JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have developed a Spring MVC Application using the below tools and technologies and it is working fine without any issue.

1. **Spring Framework** (Core, MVC & JDBC) 4.2.5.RELEASE
2. **Java 1.8**
3. **Maven 3.3.9**
4. **Eclipse IDE** (Neon 2. Release 4.6.2)
5. **Oracle JDBC** - ojdbc6 Version: 11.2.0.3

Now, I want to use OpenJDK-8 instead of Oracle JDK-8. How can we use OpenJDK in Spring MVC Project?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install OpenJDK on machines, where you want to build and run your projects, set `JAVA_HOME` to point to OpenJDK and that's it. Same for IDEs (Eclipse).

No need to change maven config since java version is not really depends on JDK vendor.